# enable zoom in ng-pdf on ionic/angularJS

Tags: angularjs, pdf, ionic-framework

I'm trying to zoom my pdf opened with this plugin:

https://github.com/sayanee/angularjs-pdf

how can i active the zoom?

```
<script id="pdf-viewer.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <ion-modal-view>
            <ion-header-bar>
                <h1 class="title">Report</h1>
                <button ng-click="vm.modal.hide()" class="button button-icon icon ion-android-close comp"></button>
            </ion-header-bar>
            <ion-content>
                <ng-pdf ng-if="pdfUrl" template-url="partials/viewer.html" canvasid="pdf" scale="page-fit"></ng-pdf>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-modal-view>
    </script>
```

viewer:

```
{{loading}}
<canvas id="pdf" class="rotate0"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ion-scroll` component. This enables ionic scrolling and zooming. However, it just draws the content once, so when you zoom everything gets blurry. I fixed this by drawing the content with 200% the size of what it was supposed to be, and then set the default zoom to 0.5. I've provided some example code below:

```
<ion-scroll max-zoom="5" overflow-scroll="false" zooming="true" direction="xy" style="width: 100%; height:100%;" scrollbar-x=false; scrollbar-y = false;>
    <img src="img/floorplan.jpg" width="200%">
</ion-scroll>
```

**Note that you have to set `overflow-scroll` to `false`, because else it would use the default ionic scrolling and zooming, which causes the zooming not to work!**